# How to determine whether an array is contained in another array

Tags: ruby

The question is, given `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[2,4,5]`, to determine whether (every element in) the second array is contained in the first one. The answer is true.

What's the most succinct and efficient way to do better than:

```
arr2.reject { |e| arr1.include?(e) } .empty?
```

Comment: What is the expectation if arrays have duplicate items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad O(n²) one-liner would look like this:

```
arr2.all? { |x| arr1.include? x }
arr2.all? &arr1.method(:include?)  # alternative
```

If your objects are hashable, you can make this O(n) by making a set out of the first array:

```
require 'set'

arr2.all? &Set.new(arr1).method(:include?)
```

If your objects are totally, like, ordered, you can make it O(n log n) with a sort and a binary search:

```
arr1.sort!
arr2.all? { |x| arr1.bsearch { |y| x <=> y } }
```

Comment: If you use Set, then why not:
`Set.new(arr2) <= Set.new(arr1)`

Comment: @Tao: Builds a second set for no time benefit, but if you like how it reads that’s important too.

Comment: I think... if you're using sets you can write: `arr1 & arr2 == arr2` as well.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: Yep, nice one.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 oh, yes, that's actually what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Tao yes it works with arrays only too (without sets) in case you want to.

Comment: and, thanks @Ryan for giving the quickest and theoretically most efficient solution. I'll mark this as best answer.

Comment: I assume it isn't efficient for large arrays, but in terms of conciseness, `(arr2 - arr1).empty?` would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: … why?

Answer (score 4):

[Array subtraction](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) should work, as in

```
(arr2 - arr1).empty?
```

Description of method:

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in [the second array]. The order is preserved from the
>   original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

I don't consider myself an expert on efficiency, but @Ryan indicated in comments to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43175007/7151673) that it's reasonably efficient at scale.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ryan you can use sets. In which case [`Set#subset?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subset-3F) is available to you which is pretty readable (note the two different ways of defining a set from an array):

```
require 'set'

s1 = Set.new([1, 2, 3])
s2 = [1, 2].to_set
s3 = [1, 3].to_set
s4 = [1, 4].to_set

s1.subset? s1 #=> true
s2.subset? s1 #=> true
s3.subset? s1 #=> true
s4.subset? s1 #=> false
```

Also consider using [`Set#proper_subset`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-proper_subset-3F) if required.

```
s1.proper_subset? s1 #=> false
s2.proper_subset? s1 #=> true
```

---

**NB** A set contains no duplicate elements e.g. `Set.new([1,2,3,3]) #=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>`